# Detect if action is show or edit in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a middleware that detects if a user owns a tournament.

So, if user want to edit a tournament he doesn't own, he will get a 403.

Thing is I can't make difference between laravel.dev/tournament/1/edit, and laravel.devl/tournament/1

Off course, I could check the "edit" word in URL, but I would prefer other better param...

I tried method param in Request Object, but it is giving me GET for both, so I can't make difference...

Any Idea???

Comment: `$request->route()->getName()` This would give you the route name. Now you can allow or deny the request.

Comment: There is nothing bad in checking the route, for example, the `edit` part with a combination of `method` checking but you may check the name as other comment mentioned.

Comment: @JilsonThomas your answer is the best for me. Please put is as answer specifying that I can check against "show" in $request->route()->... tx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can do like this:

```
$request->route()->getName();
```

Now you can do your logic based on this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should just use route specific middleware instead of global middleware.  See https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes.  Then you can just do:

```
Route::get('/tournament/{id}/edit', ['middleware' => ['tournamentOwner'], function () {
//
}]);

Route::get('/tournament/{id}', ['middleware' => [], function () {
//
}]);
```

If it's a RESTful route, you can just do:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('tournamentOwner', ['only' => ['edit']]);
}
```

Comment: The routes are resource/restful I assumed.

Comment: yep, but I'm using it as your answer

Answer (score 0):

What about using a different HTTP method for edit, e.g `PATCH` or `PUT` and declaring two different routes, something like:

```
Route::get('laravel.devl/tournament/1', 'TournamentController@showTournament');
Route::put('laravel.dev/tournament/1/edit', 'TournamentController@editTournament');
```

Then in the TournamentController you can check if the user has rights to edit.

Comment: Because the routes are resource/restful I assumed.

Comment: put will be used when calling update, while get is calling when showing edit page